# How do you aggregate metric in Prometheus with a date range defined in absolute terms

Tags: prometheus

I know it is possible to query prometheus to give you a range vector over a period of time. It is also possible to apply an offset to move this range vector. However...

up[1h] will give me a range vector for each hour starting with current time. Example, if it's 11:25 you'd get 11:25-10:25, 10:25-9:25, etc.

How do I instead ask for a range vector split by each "full" hour, ie. 9:00-10:00, 10:00-11:00, 11:00-11:25.